# Как с одного модуля закрыть другой?

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Добрый вечер, есть несколько вопросов.

1) Сервер и клиент, если закрывать в следующей последовательности (клиент а после сервер) - все нормально, но если наоборот, клиент звереет и начинает есть ЦП до 100%. Собственно хочу закрыть все клиенты если сервер убит. Или узнать почему они звереют, есть мысль что это из за связи с сервером(сокета после того как клиент соединяется с сервером). 
Пытался закрыть через сервер, то есть у меня есть массив клиентов, и я хотел пройтись по нему и поотключать их всех. но наткнулся на

**Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException**

И куча всевозможных матов из разных классов по этому пути

**at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.text**

как я понял он мягко говоря послал меня из за того что я главным потоком сервера лезу в клиент. Идей как можно решить эту проблему уже не осталось, подскажите пожалуйста.

Код связей клиента и сервера ниже.

**Сервер**

```
threadListenerNewClient = new Thread(new Runnable() {                                                                                                    
  @Override
        public void run() {
            listenerAllTime();
        }
    });
    threadListenerNewClient.start();
private void listenerAllTime() {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9630)){
        while (true){
            new TCPConnection(this, serverSocket.accept());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

**Клиент**

```
try {
tcpConnection = new TCPConnection(this, HOST, PORT);
} catch (IOException e) {
onException(this.tcpConnection, e);}
```

**TCP**

```
public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener tCPClient, String ip, int port) throws IOException {
   this(tCPClient, new Socket(ip,port));}
public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener tCPClient, Socket socket) throws IOException{
   this.tCPClient = tCPClient;
   this.socket = socket;

   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
   out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                tCPClient.onConnectionReady(TCPConnection.this);
                while (!thread.isInterrupted()) {
                    tCPClient.onReceiveString(TCPConnection.this, in.readLine());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                tCPClient.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
            } finally {
                tCPClient.onDisconnect(TCPConnection.this);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

2) Сделал jar(ки) сервера и клиента, при закрытии в нормальной последовательности оставались фоновые процессы. 
Левые потоки тушу так thread.interrupt()(в итоге матов вся консоль) но по идее все работает. И фоновых процессов(от сервера\клиента) не наблюдается. 
Может есть другие способы закрытия потоков ? ведь есть проекты с использованием множества потоков и закрывать каждый отдельно довольно проблематично. Мне не в лом, но хочу узнать, может есть еще какие-то варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) NullPointerException в клиенте?
Проверьте, что происходит при вызове `onException(this.tcpConnection, e)`, если tcpConnection=null.

Еще есть небольшое подозрение, что спуталась между собой логика клиента и сервера.
Может стоит вместо одного класса `TCPConnection` написать два отдельных?

2) Прервать `serverSocket.accept()` можно из другого потока,
вызовом `serverSocket.close()`. При этом в потоке сервера словите исключение
`java.net.SocketException`.

Также можно перед вызовом `accept()` установить таймаут `setSoTimeout(1000)` и проверять
какой-нибудь флаг завершения в обработчике исключения `java.io.InterruptedIOException`.

Сообщения на консоль вы ведь сами и выводите через `e.printStackTrace()`.
Видимо некоторые должны быть обработаны соответсвующим образом, а не просто выведены.

<strike>Кстати, чтобы разработка вашего продукта стала легче, стоит
сделать два отдельных проекта (чтоб было открыто два отдельных окна Intellij Idea) —
один для сервера, а другой для клиента. Так вы сможете запустить одновременно два отладчика.</strike>

А еще часто пишут, что после отладки работы с java.net, возможно, придется все переписать на NIO или Netty...

Comment: Я согласен с вами что удобней будет с переносом на 2 окна intellij idea. Но это мой первый проект, всю суть я взял с урока от GeekBrains. В дальнейшем я перенесу все на 2 отдельных проекта. и хочу уточнить (в вашем совете - "Может стоит вместо одного класса TCPConnection написать два отдельных?")
то есть для клиента создать  tcp - который будет формировать клиентский сокет, а на стороне сервера создать tcp- который будет отвечать только за подключение ?.
Еще хотел бы спросить по поводу видимости проэктов. К примеру я с сервера (1 проэкт) хочу достучаться к клиенту(2)проекту  как это сделать?

Comment: Разделять ли код - решать Вам, но подумайте на таким вариантом: клиент может продолжать использовать сокеты java.net, а вот сервер, как бутылочное горлышко, может потребовать асинхронной работы с сетью (например, его можно реализовать с помощью Vertx.io - вполне приятной обертки над Netty). И код работы с сетью будет совсем-совсем разный (и подход, и api).

Comment: По поводу разделения проектов - оказалось, что пользоваться проще не становится, а конструкция получается сложнее. Так что пользуйтесь модулями, как и сейчас.